# All Same Lengths Function

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function `[a] -> Bool` which returns true when all elements of the list have the same lengths.

I tried to do this using list recursion and extracted the first two elements of the list with `x : y : xs` then compared the length of x and y with `length x == length y` as case determination. However, `GHCi` complains about the types of x and y:

```
Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `[a0]'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by

      the type signature for [a] -> Bool
In the first argument of `length', namely `x'
In the first argument of `(==)', namely `length x'
In the expression: length x == length y
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix it? Clearly, `length :: [a] -> Int == length :: [a] -> Int` returns a `Bool` which is correct. In fact, replacing this expression by `True` compiles.

Comment: Your function should have type `[[a]] -> Bool`.

Comment: @Lee: That works but why can't I do `[a] -> Bool` and apply it on `Integer` or `String` lists?

Comment: Because `Integer` lists, e.g. `[Integer]` are not lists where each element has a notion of `length`. Only lists themselves have `lengths`, thus if you want to compare the lengths of some collection of things, you need a collection of lists: `[[a]]`.

Comment: The input to your function is a list of lists (of Integer or String or ...) and it returns a Bool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do this very simply, actually.

```
 sameLengths :: [[a]] -> Bool
 sameLengths [] = True
 sameLengths (x:xs) = all (\y -> length y == length x) xs
```

No need for any recursion - all of the lengths are the same iff they are equal to the first one, so just extract the first and use `all` to easily check the rest.

As for why you can't define for `[a]`, remember that `[String]` is a `[[a]]` as well as an `[a]`. But we specifically need `[[a]]` because `length` must be defined for whatever `a` is in `[a]`.

Comment: @ThreeFx oops fixed, thanks. Initially I wanted to just write `(== length x) . length` (which I prefer) but figured that it would be better to write the explicit lambda for clarity

Comment: @amalloy well I assume we are only considering finite lengths given that infinite lists... are infinite and have no length, so you could never tell if for example [[1..], [1..]] should return true or false. It is pointless to consider them for this problem.

Comment: Obviously if every list is infinite you can't answer the question, but if only some of them are there's no reason to fail to answer it.

Comment: Additionally, this answer calls `length x` N-1 times if there are N lists: if you're going to use `length`, surely it's better to save its result in a `where` clause or something.

Comment: @amalloy You are right, but I would assume that ghc's optimizer isn't broken. I think its pretty likely that `length x` only gets computed once under `-O2`. I think breaking on infinite inputs is much better behavior than breaking on only some infinite inputs.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. the `length` function is defined on lists (`length :: [a] -> Int`), so you
   can not apply it to other types
2. you can certainly define a your own class:

   ```
   class WithLength a where
       myLength :: a -> Bool
   ```

   but you must define an instance of this class for each possible type! For example:

   ```
   instance WithLength Int where
       myLength _ = 1

   instance WithLength [a] where
       myLength lst = length lst
   ```

   Then, you can define you recursive function to check the same length properies.

Answer (score 0):

The answers given so far don't work well when at least one list is list is finite and at least one is infinite: the function fails to terminate, when termination is possible, because they are busy calling `length` on an infinite list. Below is an answer that works for any sort of list:

```
allSameLength :: [[a]] -> Bool
allSameLength [] = True
allSameLength xs = all null xs || all (not . null) xs && allSameLength (map tail xs)
```

It's a pretty easy recursive definition: either all the lists are empty, or none of them are empty and they're still the same length after you take out one element from each.